# With django-tables2 how do I display a model @property?

Tags: django-models, django-tables2

I have a `@property` in my model which is basically a string of several values in the model combined.

```
  @property
    def mfg_link(self):
        return ''.join('http://mfg.com/model/' + str(self.model_numer))
```

I can add this `mfg_link` to the `list_display` on the admin model and it works fine, but its not showing up in the generated table when I pass the queryset to the table, the other fields show up fine.

This seems like something obvious, but unfortunately the couple of hours of searching didn't help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm... if I use field=('mfg_link',) in the view, I can get it to come through.

I'll let this sit for a bit and see if someone has a better explanation or thinks this is a bug.

Comment: OK, when you attempt to sort that column and the URL is updated with ?sort=mfg_link you get a fieldError. So it appears as though this is a problem with Django-Tables2 to my eye.

Comment: Well its not a problem, property method returns a value from that class object, not a field of the Model class(It doesn't exist in DB), so obviously u can't query using that property method. So u need to use different order_by for table colums displayed using property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this in Table class:

```
class TableClass(tables.Table):
   mfg_link = tables.Column('mfg_link', order_by='model_numer')

   class Meta:
     model = SomeModel
     sequence = 'model_numer', 'mfg_link'
```

Comment: With a tiny correct, adding this to the view worked! The order_by('field') should be order_by='field'. Thank you!