# django how to use property to create a column entry

Tags: django

I have a django model

```
class Process(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start_utc = models.TimeField(db_column='start', null=True, blank=True)
    end_utc = models.TimeField(db_column='end', null=True, blank=True)
```

and I want to add a property should_run

I tried to use the @property method as shown in

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/
```

where the @property is used without having an attribute in the class definition

```
class Process(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start_utc = models.TimeField(db_column='start', null=True, blank=True)
    end_utc = models.TimeField(db_column='end', null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def should_run(self):
        now = dt.datetime.utcnow().time()
        print(self.__str__(), now, self.start_utc, self.end_utc)
        return self.start_utc < now < self.end_utc
```

But this way there is not column entry created at all.

I also tried to do it the classic way

```
class Process(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start_utc = models.TimeField(db_column='start', null=True, blank=True)
    end_utc = models.TimeField(db_column='end', null=True, blank=True)
    _should_run = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_column="should_run")

    @property
    def should_run(self):
        now = dt.datetime.utcnow().time()
        print(self.__str__(), now, self.start_utc, self.end_utc)
        return self.start_utc < now < self.end_utc

    @should_run.setter
    def should_run(self, val):
        self._should_run = val
```

This way, when I render the table I get from the Model, I have a column should_run but it appears the getter is never called and the column value will always be the initial default.

How can make this work such that it would create a column with values it gets from the @property getter?

EDIT: 
The table I use is derived from the model

```
from .models import Process

class ProcessTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Process
        template_name = 'django_tables2/semantic.html'
```

The table will be rendered

```
from .models import Process
from .tables import ProcessTable

def index(request):
    p = Process.objects.all()
    context = dict(table=ProcessTable(p))
    return render(request, 'processes/index.html', context)
```

What I am trying to get is a rendered table that shows 4 columns

```
name, start_utc, end_utc, should_run
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Why do you want a column for this?

Comment: because I want to render the table and have some columns that have values set by properties as compared to static values in the DB

Comment: That didn't answer the question. A property will allow you to display the value already. Why do you think you need a column in the db?

Comment: Sorry, I dont need a column in the database, but I think that is what is required to such that my Table which is derived from the model will contain that column (see edit)

Comment: What does the sentence `But this way there is not column entry created at all.` means?

Comment: When I get the dataset and render it into a table, the table does not contain a column with that attribute (I added the rendering part I use in the views. py. I hope that makes it clearer what I am trying to achieve)

Comment: You should have explained earlier that you are using django-tables and were taking about a column on the page, not in the db. You can just add your column to  ProcessTable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736973/with-django-tables2-how-do-i-display-a-model-property

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear. Thanks for the link. That looks like what was as looking for